# Computing Phase Response: do we reform equations to the form $e^{j\phi(\omega)} C(e^{j\omega})$?

Tags: continuous-signals, phase

I want to understand how we derive the Phase Response.

The general formula is $H(e^{j\omega})=|H(e^{j\omega})|e^{j\phi(\omega)}$

Came across an example where:

$H(e^{j\omega})=2\cos(\omega)e^{-j\omega}$

And the phase result is

$\phi(\omega)= \omega \vee-\omega +\phi$

Do I get it right that in this example the phase response is derived from the exponent of $e^{-j\omega}$, because with regard to the formula for the frequency function it is $-\omega$? So is it right, that if we can derive such form, we ignore $|H(e^{j\omega})|?$ And if we have one term of e to the power of something, we can conclude that the second term is the magnitude response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to compute the argument of a complex number. If the frequency response is expressed as

$$H(e^{j\omega})=A(\omega)e^{j\phi(\omega)}\tag{1}$$

then $A(\omega)$ is the magnitude and $\phi(\omega)$ is the phase, **only if** $A(\omega)$ is real-valued and non-negative.

So in your example $H(e^{j\omega})=2\cos(\omega)e^{-j\omega}$, the phase equals $-\omega$ only in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, because otherwise $\cos(\omega)$ is negative. For $\pi/2<|\omega|<\pi$, you have to add $\pm\pi$ to the phase to compensate for the sign inversion of the cosine. Hence, the phase is given by

$$\phi(\omega)=\begin{cases}-\omega,&0\le|\omega|\le\pi/2\\-\omega\pm\pi,&\pi/2<|\omega|<\pi\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

With the phase defined in that way, we can rewrite the given frequency response in terms of magnitude and phase:

$$H(e^{j\omega})=2|\cos(\omega)|e^{j\phi(\omega)}\tag{3}$$